# identical headers in my tables are displaying differently

Tags: mysql, css

I'm running queries and loading the results into tables for display. Several of the queries are pulling the same data yet it's displaying differently in the tables. For example, **Point of Contact** is displaying differently on 1 of 3 tables. The tables are being displayed in `iframes` pulled from separate web pages.

```
table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid green;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1px;
}

th {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}

table { 
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

iframe {
    display: block; /*new*/
    margin: auto;
    border: none; /*revised*/
    width: 800px;
    height: 200px;
}

div.center p {
    text-align: center;
} /*new*/ 

<div class="center">
    <p>
        <button onclick="myFunction1()">Current Projects</button>
        <button onclick="myFunction2()">Completed Projects</button>
        <button onclick="myFunction3()">Projects in Final Review</button>
    </p>
</div>

<script>
    var iframeExists = false;

    function myFunction1() {
        var x
        if (!iframeExists) {
            x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
            iframeExists = true;
        } else {
            x = document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME")[0];
        }
        x.setAttribute("src", "http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/CurrentProjects.php");
        document.body.appendChild(x);
    }

    function myFunction2() {
        var x;
        if (!iframeExists) {
            x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
            iframeExists = true;
        } else {
            x = document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME")[0];
        }
        x.setAttribute("src", "http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/CompletedProjects.php");
        document.body.appendChild(x);
    }

    function myFunction3() {
        var x;
        if (!iframeExists) {
            x = document.createElement("IFRAME");
            iframeExists = true;
        } else {
            x = document.getElementsByTagName("IFRAME")[0];
        }
        x.setAttribute("src", "http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/ProjectsInFinalReview.php");
        document.body.appendChild(x);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting cookies?

Comment: @LearningProcess, no I haven't.  I'm not sure what effect that would have on why the columns with the same data are rendering differently on other pages.

Comment: I believe he means your cache. You are loading IFrames, each with their own CSS which will be cached by your browser. If you Inspect Element (on Chrome) or use the Developer Tools for whichever browser you are most familiar with, do you see different CSS applied to the different tables? It also doesn't help that we can't really see the HTML (unless we follow your links).

Comment: @noahnu the onclick events are used to run queries on their respective pages.  All you would see on this page "http://www.oldgamer60.com/Project/CurrentProjects.php"); is the html.  That page has the same css link as every other page on my domain.

Comment: @noahnu <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystylesheet.css">
    <title>Tech Order Department.html</title>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8" />


</head>

<body>

    
    <h2>Current Projects</h2>
<br>

<table><tr><th>Client</th><th>Project</th><th>Point of Contact</th><th>Date Project Received</th></tr><tr><td>NASA</td><td>Mobile Fuel Stand</td><td> Moore</td><td> 2015-10-08</td></tr><tr><td>True Systems</td><td>HVAC Reclimination</td><td> Foiles</td><td> 2015-11-01</td></tr></table> 

  </body>
</html>

Comment: btw, what do you mean "displaying differently"?

Comment: @noahnu for example Point of Contact is on three pages.  In two of them it dislays on a single line and on the third page it displays in two lines.  The names in the Point of Contact column also display in a similar fashion.

Comment: You should edit your post and add in all necessary information. I'd say the actual issue i.e. header appears on multiple lines should be in your question. If you don't want text to be displayed on multiple lines, use [`white-space: nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94325/discussion-between-tony-and-noahnu).